# compile error when calling pointer to a member function in other class

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have created a class A as following in "A.h" and it has a public function func(int)

```
class A {
   public:
   A();
   int func(int val);
   ...
}
```

and a class B in "B.h" has class A as member and a typedef of pointer to above function.

```
class B {
   typedef int (A::*m_func)(int);
public:
   B();
   private:
   A      myA;
   m_func _ptrFunc;
   ...
}
```

in B.cpp assign a function in class A to B's member function

```
_ptrFunc = &myA.func
```

But when I try to pass an argument to _ptrFunc like this

```
if(_ptrFunc) {
   y = (this->*_ptrFunc)(x)
   ...
}
```

I get below error

error: pointer to member type 'int (A::)(int)' incompatible with object type 'A'
y = (this->*_ptrFunc)(x);

What is correct way of accessing the function pointer to other class?

Comment: `(myA.*_ptrFunc)(x)`

Comment: Wow thanks! this works.